# Como criar o serviço de um controller?

Tags: angularjs

Olá, eu gostaria de saber se é possível com este código criar um serviço. Pois todos os vídeos que vejo eles apenas criam serviços para coisas que serão duplicadas no código e afins ou de links do localhost. Se for possível me ajudar, agradeço.

```
angular.module('TarefApp')

.controller('TarefasController', function($scope) {
    $scope.categorias = [
        {nome:'Tarefas Primárias'},
        {nome:'Tarefas Secundárias'},
    ];
    $scope.tarefas = [];
    $scope.categoriaTarefa = {tarefa:{}};     

    $scope.addTarefa = function(tarefa) {
        if(!$scope.categoriaSelecionada){
            alert("Selecione uma categoria!")
            return;
        }

        var c = $scope.categoriaSelecionada;

        if(!$scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c])
        $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c] = [];
        else{
            var itemDuplicado = false;
            angular.forEach($scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c], function (item, index){
                itemDuplicado = (item.nome === tarefa.nome);
                if(itemDuplicado){
                    alert("Tarefa para categoria já existe!");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        if(!itemDuplicado){
            $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c].push(tarefa);
            $scope.tarefa = {};
        }
    };

    $scope.delTarefas = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.categorias, function(item) {
            var c = item.nome;
            var oldTarefas = $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c];
            $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c] = [];

            angular.forEach(oldTarefas, function(tar) {
                if (!tar.selecionado) $scope.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c].push(tar);
            });
        });
    };

    $scope.addCategoria = function(categoria) {
        for(var i=0; i < $scope.categorias.length; i++){
            if($scope.categorias[i].nome === categoria.nome){
                alert("A categoria já existe!");
                return;
            }
        }
        $scope.categorias.push(angular.copy(categoria));
        delete $scope.categoria;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [...]é possível com este código criar um serviço[?].

**Sim, é possível.** Na verdade, da maneira como seu *controller* foi escrito, a conversão para um serviço se torna muito simples. Você só precisa levar em consideração alguns pontos:

**Serviços não possuem $scope**

Serviços em Angular são *singletons* - o que significa que apenas uma instância é criada. Como `$scope` é uma ferramenta do Angular para referenciar o contexto de cada instância, ele é desnecessário. Neste caso, você precisa  converter todas as menções de `$scope` para `this`.

**Referências para this em funções precisam ser revisadas**

Um ponto adicional que você precisa ter em mente é que o javascript irá criar um escopo para cada chamada de função, e `this` sempre aponta para o contexto atual.

A solução é criar uma referência ao escopo principal (`var that = this`, no meu exemplo), e utilizar esta referência ao invés de `this` dentro de uma função (`!that.categoriaSelecionada`).

A versão convertida do seu código vem a seguir:

```js
angular.module('TarefaApp', []);

angular.module('TarefaApp')
    .service('TarefasService', function() {
        var that = this;

        this.categorias = [
            {nome:'Tarefas Primárias'},
            {nome:'Tarefas Secundárias'},
        ];
        this.tarefas = [];
        this.categoriaTarefa = {tarefa:{}};     
        this.categoriaSelecionada = {};

        this.addTarefa = function(tarefa) {
            if(!that.categoriaSelecionada){
                alert("Selecione uma categoria!")
                return;
            }

            var c = that.categoriaSelecionada;

            if(!that.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c])
            that.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c] = [];
            else{
                var itemDuplicado = false;
                angular.forEach(that.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c], function (item, index){
                    itemDuplicado = (item.nome === tarefa.nome);
                    if(itemDuplicado){
                        alert("Tarefa para categoria já existe!");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

            if(!itemDuplicado){
                that.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c].push(tarefa);
                that.tarefa = {};
            }
        };

        this.delTarefas = function() {
            angular.forEach(that.categorias, function(item) {
                var c = item.nome;
                var oldTarefas = that.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c];
                that.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c] = [];

                angular.forEach(oldTarefas, function(tar) {
                    if (!tar.selecionado) that.categoriaTarefa.tarefa[c].push(tar);
                });
            });
        };

        this.addCategoria = function(categoria) {
            for(var i=0; i < that.categorias.length; i++){
                if(that.categorias[i].nome === categoria.nome){
                    alert("A categoria já existe!");
                    return;
                }
            }
            that.categorias.push(angular.copy(categoria));
            delete that.categoria;
        };
    })
.controller('TarefasController', function($scope, TarefasService) {
  $scope.svc = TarefasService;
})
.controller('Tarefas2Controller', function($scope, TarefasService) {
  $scope.svc = TarefasService;
});
```

```html
<html ng-app='TarefaApp'>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="TarefasController">
      Controle 1:<br/>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model='svc.categoriaSelecionada'>
        <option ng-repeat="categoria in svc.categorias">{{categoria.nome}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="Tarefas2Controller">
      Controle 2:<br/>
      {{svc.categoriaSelecionada}}
      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Observe como o valor selecionado no *Controller 1* é compartilhado, via serviço, com o *Controller 2*.

Comment: Acredito que esteja faltando parte do código no final que provavelmente faz o código funcionar.

Comment: @LarissaMourullo Err... obrigado, você está correta; faltou copiar as linhas finais do serviço. Post editado e corrigido.

Comment: muito obrigada de verdade, achei bem fácil como foi feito. Me ajudou bastante.

Comment: @LarissaMourullo Sempre um prazer! Tendo mais dúvidas, sinta-se à vontade para perguntar.

Comment: estou tentando fazer funcionar, mas nada ta acontecendo (OBS: nenhum erro ocorrendo). Estou colocando isso no controller para chamar os serviços: .controller('TarefasController', function($scope, TarefasService) {

Comment: @LarissaMourullo Eu alterei o post, incluindo um exemplo de controle consumindo seu serviço.

Answer (score 6):

**O que é um serviço em angular?**

Um serviço em angular serve para compartilhar recursos entre controladores. O uso mais comum nesse caso é a utilização desse recurso para criar uma interface de comunicação http comum. Por exemplo, você pode ter um serviço chamado pessoa e usar esse em diferentes controladores. Esse serviço irá prover uma interfac de acesso a dados para toda a aplicação no que se referir a uma pessoa (consultar, editar, incluir e etc).

```
app.controller('PessoaController', function($scope, $pessoa) {
    $scope.cadastrar = function (){
        $pessoa.cadastrar('<passa aqui dados pessoa>');
    };

    $scope.excluir = function (){
        $pessoa.cadastrar('<passa aqui id pessoa>');
    };

    $scope.consultarPorId = function (){
        $pessoa.cadastrar('<passa aqui id pessoa>');
    };
});

app.controller('VendaController', function($scope, $pessoa, $venda) {
    $scope.incluir = function (){
        $scope.consultarPorId(idPessoa).then(efetivarVenda);
    };

    $scope.efetivarVenda = function(pessoa){
        var venda = {/* Aqui monta objeto venda */};
        venda.pessoa = pessoa;
        $venda.efetivar(venda);
    };

    $scope.consultarPorId = function (){
        $pessoa.cadastrar('<passa aqui id pessoa>');
    };
});
```

Nesse exemplo você pode identificar o serviço $pessoa e o $venda. O serviço pessoa é compartilhado entre dois controladores, PessoaController e VendaController. A idéia do serviço é justamente essa. Compartilhar interfaces comuns entre os controladores.

**É possível usar um controlador para encapsular métodos comuns?**

Sim! É possível, entretanto não recomendo. Um serviço tem algumas limitações que podem dar mais dor de cabeça do que ajudar. Como já mencionado o serviço deve prover uma interface de comunicação entre outro sistema ou ainda entre serviços.

**Como posso fazer para criar um ponto único de acesso a funções comuns no sistema?**

Você criar um modulo commons que pode prover esses métodos comuns.

```
var commom = angular.module("utils.commom", []);
commom.factory("$commomutils", function($http, $q, $injector) {
    return({
        fazAlgo:function(algumaCoisa){
            console.log(algumaCoisa);
        }
    });
});

var appQualquer = angular.module("AppQualquer", ["utils.commom"]);
appQualquer.controller("ControllerQualquer", function($scope, $commomutils) {
    $scope.iniciar = function() {
        $commomutils.fazAlgo("JEC não vai cair!!! Figueira freguês!!!");
    };
});

appQualquer.directive("diretiva", [function () {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
    replace : true,
    link : function(scope, element, attr) {
            angular.element(element).html("Figueira FREGUES!!! JEC Maior de SC");
    }
    };
}]);
```

Observe o módulo **utils.commom** e como o mesmo é injetado no AppQualquer. Dessa forma você pode centralizar seus métodos comuns tendo um acesso a todos os recursos necessários.

Answer (score 3):

Este código apresentado por você poderia sim ser convertido em serviço, a questão é que o que ele faz, não é o comportamento de um serviço angular.

No geral, serviços oferecem acesso a recursos ou funcionalidades partilhadas por toda aplicação, exemplos disso são, chamadas a servidor, informações do usuário e coisas do tipo.

Já os controladores, são estruturas para comandar os comportamentos de uma tela, eventos de botão, chamadas aos serviços. Perceba que é justamente isso o que o seu controlador atual faz.

Neste link você encontra um exemplo simples de criação de serviço: http://techbusters.com.br/criar-servico-com-angularjs/ mas os melhores posts sobre o assunto estão em inglês, caso queira mais informações a pesquisa "angular service" deve lhe retornar resultados satisfatórios.